# Failing to run a deboundced react onChange using vitest advanceTimersByTime

Tags: reactjs, debouncing, vitest

I have the test below

[image: Test]

Which I am running on a reusable text field that has a debounce function as below (code slightly trimmed)

[image: Reusable textfield]

For some reason I keep getting the error below despite using `vitest.useFakeTimers()`. Outside of the fact that debounce is `500ms` and the test is `2000ms`Is there something I am missing?

```
Error: Timers are not mocked. Try calling "vi.useFakeTimers()" first.


 act(() => {
    vi.advanceTimersByTime(2000);
      ^
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well something like this worked

```
function delay(timeout: number | undefined) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
    });
}
```

test

```
    test('should render task name', async () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<Wrapper />);
        const taskName = await waitFor(() => getByTestId('task').querySelector('input'));
        const taskNameTextfield = taskName as HTMLInputElement;
        fireEvent.input(taskNameTextfield, {
            target: {
                value: 'task'
            }
        });

        await act(async () => {
            await delay(1000);
        });
        
        await waitFor(() => expect(taskNameTextfield.value).toEqual('task'));
    });
```